# return form in JSON and put it as nested element in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a form from HTML that return a JSON object, but I want that data in a nested JSON.

Here is my HTML

```
    <form role="form" ng-submit="submitWorkshop()">
   <div>
     <div ng-repeat="x in form">
       <h4>{{x.field_label}}</h4>
          <div ng-switch on="x.field_ui_type">
             <textarea class="form-control" ng-switch-when="textarea" placeholder="{{x.field_name}}" ng-model="result.Table_Name[x.field_name]"></textarea>
            <input class="form-control" ng-switch-when="input" placeholder="{{x.field_name}}" ng-model="result.Table_Name[x.field_name]">

          </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <hr>

    <div align="right">
       <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitWorkshop()">Submit</button>
       <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                        </div>
   </form>
```

and here is my angular controller

```
app.controller('createworkshopController', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get(end_url + ':' + port + '/createworkshop')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.form = data.Workshop;
        $scope.Table_Name = data.Workshop[1].table_name;
        console.log($scope.Table_Name);
    });

$scope.result = {Table_Name: {}};
$scope.submitWorkshop = function() {

    console.log($scope.result);

  // $http({method:'POST', data:$scope.result, url:'/workshopreturn'})
};
```

});

the JSON data that I get to make the form(part of it)

```
Workshop: [
{
  md_id: 35,
  form: "createworkshop",
  table_name: "d_workshop",
  field_name: "WorkshopId",
  visibility: 0,
  field_label: "Workshop ID",
  field_ui_type: "input",
  field_type: "int",
  display_order: 1,
  field_value: 0
  },...........
```

currently I can get the d_workshop in the table_name, but I tried to nest the data to back end when I tried to store the table_name in $scope.Table_Name.

now everytime when i get the JSON from html I get this

```
Table_Name: {
   Age: "a",
   Agenda: "a",
   Concept: "a",
   CurriculumId: "a",
   Objectives: "a",
   Subject: "a",
   TargetNoOfStudents: "a",
   Title: "a",
   WorkshopId: "a",
}
```

but I want it to be dynamic, in this case should be

```
d_workshop: {
   Age: "a",
   Agenda: "a",
   Concept: "a",
   CurriculumId: "a",
   Objectives: "a",
   Subject: "a",
   TargetNoOfStudents: "a",
   Title: "a",
   WorkshopId: "a",
}
```

please help

Comment: $scope.result = {Table_Name: {}}; Shouldn't this be $scope.result = {$scope.Table_Name: {}};

Comment: let me try it, but how about the HTML part, should the ng-model be result.Table_Name[x.field_name] or is it something else

Comment: That would create an error.